# Is Runtime method

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there a way to tell in Pharo Smalltalk if the current image is a runtime image or a development image? I'm wanting create a way to signal a shutdown of a runtime image but not a development image.

Answer (score 1):

In Pharo there is a strip down capability to remove development time classes and tools , packaging it for a runtime. It is similar but not process wise same as in VA.

There is no convinience method to check if its a runtime vs dev. But adding one is cheap in Smalltalk.. so go ahead and add it to

SmalltalkImage >> isRuntime

```
^( Smalltalk at: #Metacello1 ifAbsent: [ ] ) isNil
```

"or any class you guarantee is not present in runtime image at all times in runtime and always present in dev..

ImageCleaner>> offers methods to clean up for Production / Release.. and give some more leg up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in distinction as "runtime" vs. "development" in a Smalltalk image. But, since it's a live environment, you can indicate this however you want e.g. via a singleton. Something like:

```
SessionType class>>uniqueInstance
  ^ uniqueInstance ifNil: [ uniqueInstance := self new ]

SessionType>>isDevelopment
  ^ isDevelopment

SessionType>>isDevelopment: aBoolean
  isDevelopment := aBoolean
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm pretty new to Pharo. All of my Smalltalk experience has been with VA Smalltalk. They used to have a method, (I believe on the System level), that denoted whether you were in a development image or a packaged runtime image.

Comment: If you found it useful, make a case on the Dev mailing list to be included in core. The community is very open to good ideas (especially when accompanied by code haha). And welcome to Pharo :)

Comment: Don't know anything about the Dev mailing list. Can you elaborate please?